# Android open "App manager" specific application from code

Tags: android, android-settings

I manage to open the app manager listing all applications with the code:

`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS), 0);`

Nevertheless, I would like to open the menu for a specific application ("for example: TestABC"), which would be the menu which appears after clicking on top of the same application from the list which opens using the code provided previously. I have checked that the `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` option (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) could be the appropiate, but I coudn't manage to make it work...

Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivityForResult(i,0);
```